# formulate a circle as a surface

Tags: matlab, surfaces

How would I describe a circle in the same way as we formulated the lateral area of a cylinder (below)? My first guess would be $\phi=(R\cos u,R\sin u,k)'$ , ($k$ being the $z$-plane where the circle would be) but then I cannot plot it because there is no '$v$'.

[image: formula of lateral area of a cylinder]

Edit: I would be plotting it in Matlab using ezsurf()

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Avoid the use of images. Your questions will be better received in this site, increasing your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to graph a **disk**, not a circle. You may parametrize it as $\phi : [0, 2\pi]\times [0,R] \to \Bbb R^3,\quad \phi(u,v) = (v \cos(u), v\sin(u), k)$